# How to configurate keycloak healthcheck in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, healthcheck

I need my BFF service to wait for keycloak to be fully launched using condition `service_health`, and then start its launch. I can't set up a health check for `keycloak`. When searching for an answer, I come across either strange or outdated answers related to `curl`, which is no longer in the new version of `keycloak`. How do I set up the `healthcheck` keycloak correctly?

```yaml
services:
  gateway:
    image: 'my-service-bff:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    container_name: 'my-service-bff'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      keycloak:
        condition: service_healthy
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: 'postgres-db'
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloakdb
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloakuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloakpass
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U keycloakuser -d keycloakdb
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
    networks:
      - keycloak-network
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
    environment:
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloakdb
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_USER: user
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: user
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    command:
      - "start-dev"
    networks:
      - 'keycloak-network'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      # Unsuccessful attempts:
      # test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://0.0.0.0:8080/realms/master" ]
      # test: ['CMD-SHELL', '[ -f /tmp/HealthCheck.java ] || echo "public class HealthCheck { public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Throwable { System.exit(java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == ((java.net.HttpURLConnection)new java.net.URI.create(args[0]).toURL().openConnection()).getResponseCode() ? 0 : 1); } }" > /tmp/HealthCheck.java && java /tmp/HealthCheck.java http://localhost:8080/health/live']
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 30s
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s

networks:
  keycloak-network:
    driver: 'bridge'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: 'local'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add Curl by using the KeyCloak image in a Dockerfile and reference that Dockerfile in your `docker-compose.yaml` file.

To do that I  create a directory inside the `docker-compose.yaml` directory and call it something simple like `KeyCloakDockerfile` and in that create your `Dockerfile so structure should look like this:

```
_
 |_ docker-compose.yaml
 |_ KeyCloakDockerfile/
   |_ Dockerfile
```

You would create the Dockerfile like so *(Assuming it's RHEL or some RedHat derivative)*:

```
###### Using As Base Image ######
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4

###### Non-Interactive Installations #########
ENV DAEMON_OPTS=-nonat
ENV TERM=xterm-256color

######### Update & Upgrade the Image ##########
RUN yum update -y && yum upgrade -y

###### Install Curl ###### 
RUN yum install -y curl

###### Use The ENTRYPOINT From The Original Images Dockerfile. ######
###### The Original Dockerfile https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak/manifest/sha256:122ff5badfb88afe1027bc8e1a9c85532148ee813bee30c01173947a445d4fe7 ######

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yaml` you can change you KeyCloak service to look like this:

```yaml
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./KeyCloakDockerfile/Dockerfile
    environment:
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloakdb
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_USER: user
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: user
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    command:
      - "start-dev"
    networks:
      - 'keycloak-network'
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck:
      # Unsuccessful attempts:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://0.0.0.0:8080/realms/master" ]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 30s
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
```

This way when you run `docker compose up -d` if the image has not been built it will build it then run it with the other Services defined in the `docker-compose.yaml`.

**SECURITY SIDENOTE !**

Looking the the repository that Image of KeyCloak we're using has some vulerabilities present as is labeled here:

https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak/manifest/sha256:122ff5badfb88afe1027bc8e1a9c85532148ee813bee30c01173947a445d4fe7?tab=vulnerabilities

It states that version **3.90.0-4.el9_3** should be upgraded to version **0:3.90.0-6.el9_3**. This should be paid attentions to when using KeyCloak as good practise.